# Path not found in setting up Apache Jena

Tags: jena

I am trying to run Apache Jena through the Windows command line. Based on the Apache Jena documentation on GitHub, I have downloaded and unzipped the Jena to `C:\Ajay\Softwares\apache-jena-4.9.0`. And I am running the following code to setup the path:

```
SET JENA_HOME =C:\Ajay\Softwares\apache-jena-4.9.0
SET PATH=%PATH%;%JENA_HOME%\bat
```

However, on running the `sparql.bat --version` command, I am getting the following error:
`'sparql.bat' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file`
Similarly, on running `cd %JENA_HOME%` command, I am getting the following error:
`The system cannot find the path specified.`

What can be the reason for this, and how to solve this issue? Thanks in advance.

Best regards,
Ajay

Comment: Echo the settign of %PATH% and chec it is as expected.
Check the syntax of the SET (e.g. no space before =)

Comment: Thanks, @AndyS, setting the PATH value in Windows settings worked.